# Azure conditional access by device name

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I want to limit access to Azure P2S VPN by computername. What I did:
I configure one conditional policy to block all users(Pol1).
Second conditional policy(Pol2):

- All Users
- In Cloud apps or actions I selected Azure VPN
- Conditions - Filter for devices - Include filtered devices in policy

  - displayName contains MyComputerName
  - deviceID equals MyDeviceID (I got it using dsrgcmd /status)
- Access controls -Grant access - Require multifactor authentication

When I am trying to connect with Azure VPN I see in Sign-in logs Pol1 failed. (Block access for all). Pol2 is Not Applied. Why? I specified to check out for Name or ID...

Next step instead of second policy I created a policy that Grant only for following:
Require multifactor authentication
Require domain-joined device

It doesn't work. I joined my computer to Azure AD - doesn't help. I still getting:
Not satisfied
Require multifactor authentication
Require domain-joined device

I am out of ideas... Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the results like below:***

I have configured point to site vpn and connected successfully like below:

[image]

To Set MFA make sure. To set **`User assignment required as Yes`** to limit sign-in to only users that have permissions to the Azure VPN like below.

***Enterprise application --> Azure VPN --> properties --> User assignment required. -> save***

[image]

*I have created group, added a limited member to access*

- In conditional access policy ->***Assignments*** -> ***Users and groups*** -> include -> ***Add group*** like below
- In Grant ***Require multi-factor authentication***
- In the **Enable policy** section -> click ***ON*** -> Create

[image]

Now when I try to connect with added group member it connected successfully.

[image]

When I try to access with another user it restricts like below

[image]

***Reference:***

[Azure AD Authentication for Point to Site (P2S) VPN - Cloudthat | CloudThat](https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/microsoft-azure-active-directory-aad-authentication-to-connect-point-to-site-vpn)

---

## Update

I tried in my environment According to your scenario i have created policy 1.

- Try to give ***block access for all user*** and in condition -> Filter& device -> ***exclude filtered device*** and provide your device id like below:

[image]

In policy 2, Now I have given ***Grant access for all user*** and you can `Add device id` and `display name` in ***include filtered device*** and grant access like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Imran, but this is not what I am looking for. In additional to giving access to specific users, I want to limit them to use only allowed computers. I want to specify computer name, ID or MAC address.

Comment: Kindly check this updated answer

Comment: Also blocking all the user is not recommended. Try to utilize **Emergency access** or **break-glass** accounts to prevent tenant-wide account lockout [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access)

Comment: I think your answer is correct. I configured as you suggested 2 policies. First - to block every one and exclude my deviceID. Second - to allow and include my deviceID. But my device still not recognized: Device
{PII Removed}
 Not matched

Comment: Your device has been removed Try to enable device check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92512/enabling-devices)

Comment: My computer still only device enabled on Active Directory. And I see that in case device was matched by conditional access PII was removed.